# Use another rule if callback returns false

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I'm using the following rule for my input:

```
callback_validate_host
```

I need to make the following condition:

if `callback_validate_host` is `FALSE` afterwards it should use the `valid_ip` validation rule.

So if validation of both: `callback_validate_host` and `valid_ip` on one input if `FALSE` then is should throw an error message.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using your existing `validate_host()` method in conjunction with the Input class' `$this->input->valid_ip($ip)` method to create a single callback? Something like this:

```
public function your_custom_rule($input) {
    if (! $this->validate_host($input) && ! $this->input->valid_ip($input)) {
        // validate_host() returned FALSE *and* it's not a valid IP
        $this->form_validation->set_message('your_custom_rule', 'Error msg');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that I can force the validation function to work separately. Thanks!

Comment: @Cyclone: Happy to help! It's worth noting that, if you look in CI's `Form_validation` library, you'll find that all the `valid_ip` rule does is reference that very function from the Input class!